# Why the maximal element in the set is a maximal right ideal?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $a$ be an element of a ring $R$, and let $A$ be the right ideal $\{ar-r \mid r \in R\}$ in $R$. If $a \notin A$, show that there is a maximal right ideal in $R$ which does not contain the element $a$.

My attempt is as follows:

Let $S = \{N \mid N \mbox{ is a right ideal in } R, a \notin N \}$. Since $A \in S$, $S$ is not empty. It is easy to show that the union of an arbitrary chain in $S$ is an element of $S$. By Zorn's Lemma, $S$ contains a maximal element $M$. Since $M \in S$, we have $a \notin M$. Thus $M \neq R$.

But I can't prove that $M$ is a maximal right ideal in $R$.

Please give me some ideas, thank you.

Comment: Are you working with rings not necessarily with identity, perhaps? If you assume identity, it is much more straightforward to prove  that a maximal right ideal containing $a-1$ exists, and it necessarily cannot contain $a$.  Without identity, this question is more interesting.

Comment: I’m not even completely sure you’re reading the question correctly. People often find this wording ambiguous. Does it mean “maximal with respect to not containing $a$? If so, you already did that. Does it mean maximal with respect to all proper ideals and it does not contain $a$? That’s what you interpreted it as.  I can’t tell for sure what the intention was as written, but the former is more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose your $M$ so that it includes $A$. Now let $U$ be a right ideal of $R$ such that  $M\subset U$. By the maximality of $M$, we must have $a\in U$.

Not let $r\in R$. Then $ar-r\in A\subseteq M\subset U$. However, $ar\in U$ as $a\in U.$ Thus,

$$ar-r- ar=-r\in U$$
That is, $r\in U\implies R=U$. Thus, $M$ is a maximal right ideal of $R$ as desired.

Comment: "You can choose your $M$ so that it includes $A$".
How to choose it? Consider $M+A$? (but I don't know why $a \notin M+A$)
Thank you.

Comment: @EnyaHsu you simply start out with a different poset: the set of ideals containing $A$ and not containing $a$. Clearly it is nonempty, and the same Zorn argument holds.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! :)